# difference between setScrollEnabled and .scrollEnabled Xcode

Tags: scroll, scrollview

What is the difference between `<scrollViewName>.scrollEnabled = YES` and `[<scrollViewName> setScrollEnabled:YES];` in xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference. `scrollEnabled` is property name and `setScrollEnabled:` is setter for this property. You may use both.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) is some information about properties and accessors.